# Kendo UI Angular date picker causes ng-sidebar to close

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datepicker, sidebar, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using Angular 5 with the Kendo Angular date picker 2.0.0 and ng-sidebar 6.0.5. I have the side bar sliding out from the left to show a search parameter form. It does not fill the entire width of the screen and I want the user to be able to click anywhere on the visible part of the underlying screen to close the sidebar. I have the closeOnClickOutside property of the sidebar set to true.

I am using the date picker for a search parameter and when the picker displays its pop up and I select a date it causes the sidebar to close, which I do not want to happen. I have narrowed it down to the date picker acting like it is not on the sidebar form because if I set the sidebar's closeOnClickOutside property to false the date picker does not cause the side bar to close/be dismissed.

Regards,
Paul

Comment: Can you post some relevant code and setup demo on stackblitz?

Comment: I'm trying to put together a plunker but I can't get the sidebar to work in it. Checking with that author.